GAMS error Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
Hello I'm learning gams studio Im trying code for spesitif question I was help with chatgpt but chatgpt didn't solution my problem
Set
    I 'Products' / Temse, Rye, Sandwich, Breadstick, Pepperoni /
    J 'Processes' / Process1, Process2 /
    T 'Months' / 1*12 /;

Parameter
    capacity 'Production capacity' / 200000 /;  # Total production capacity
Scalar cost_per_unit 'Cost per unit' / 10 /;  # Cost per unit

Table demand(I,T) 'Monthly demand data';
demand(I,T) = 
    140 95 400 355 210 165 80 1350 1065 500 310 120
    120 85 350 305 145 130 60 1065 915 310 285 95
    110 75 300 265 120 110 55 980 785 255 210 80
    170 115 450 395 225 180 105 1500 1180 685 335 195
    90 55 250 235 95 80 35 726 705 215 145 75
    130 85 350 345 145 130 60 1065 1035 310 285 95
    110 75 300 285 120 110 55 980 850 255 210 80
    100 70 275 255 110 85 40 820 765 240 130 65
    160 110 400 375 210 165 80 1350 1120 500 310 120
    80 50 225 215 80 75 30 670 645 195 115 50
    140 95 400 355 210 165 80 1350 1065 500 310 120
    90 55 250 235 95 80 35 726 705 215 145 75;

Table machine_hours(I,J) 'Machine hours per product per process';
machine_hours(I,J) = 
    4 3
    2.15 5
    2.5 3.5
    3 2
    4.15 2;

Table worker_hours(I,J) 'Worker hours per product per process';
worker_hours(I,J) = 
    12 8
    14 17
    13 9
    5 7
    11 4.5;

Parameter
    machine_capacity(T) 'Machine capacity' / 
        1 140,
        2 120,
        3 110,
        4 170,
        5 90,
        6 130,
        7 110,
        8 100,
        9 160,
        10 80,
        11 140,
        12 90 /;

Parameter
    worker_capacity(T) 'Worker capacity' / 
        1 95,
        2 85,
        3 75,
        4 115,
        5 55,
        6 85,
        7 75,
        8 70,
        9 110,
        10 50,
        11 95,
        12 55 /;

Variables
    P(I,J,T) 'Product production' binary;

Positive Variable
    total_cost 'Total cost';

Equations
    objective 'Objective function',
    capacity_constraint 'Capacity constraint';

objective.. total_cost =e= cost_per_unit * sum((I,J,T), P(I,J,T));

capacity_constraint.. sum((I,J,T), machine_hours(I,J)*P(I,J,T) + worker_hours(I,J)*P(I,J,T)) =l= capacity;

Model production_optimization /all/;
Solve production_optimization using mip minimizing total_cost;

Display P.L, total_cost.l;


it is my code
Set
    I 'Products' / Temse, Rye, Sandwich, Breadstick, Pepperoni /
    J 'Processes' / Process1, Process2 /
    T 'Months' / 1*12 /;

Parameter
    capacity 'Production capacity' / 200000 /;  # Total production capacity
Scalar cost_per_unit 'Cost per unit' / 10 /;  # Cost per unit

Table demand(I,T) 'Monthly demand data';
demand(I,T) = 
    140 95 400 355 210 165 80 1350 1065 500 310 120
    120 85 350 305 145 130 60 1065 915 310 285 95
    110 75 300 265 120 110 55 980 785 255 210 80
    170 115 450 395 225 180 105 1500 1180 685 335 195
    90 55 250 235 95 80 35 726 705 215 145 75
    130 85 350 345 145 130 60 1065 1035 310 285 95
    110 75 300 285 120 110 55 980 850 255 210 80
    100 70 275 255 110 85 40 820 765 240 130 65
    160 110 400 375 210 165 80 1350 1120 500 310 120
    80 50 225 215 80 75 30 670 645 195 115 50
    140 95 400 355 210 165 80 1350 1065 500 310 120
    90 55 250 235 95 80 35 726 705 215 145 75;

Table machine_hours(I,J) 'Machine hours per product per process';
machine_hours(I,J) = 
    4 3
    2.15 5
    2.5 3.5
    3 2
    4.15 2;

Table worker_hours(I,J) 'Worker hours per product per process';
worker_hours(I,J) = 
    12 8
    14 17
    13 9
    5 7
    11 4.5;

Parameter
    machine_capacity(T) 'Machine capacity' / 
        1 140,
        2 120,
        3 110,
        4 170,
        5 90,
        6 130,
        7 110,
        8 100,
        9 160,
        10 80,
        11 140,
        12 90 /;

Parameter
    worker_capacity(T) 'Worker capacity' / 
        1 95,
        2 85,
        3 75,
        4 115,
        5 55,
        6 85,
        7 75,
        8 70,
        9 110,
        10 50,
        11 95,
        12 55 /;

Variables
    P(I,J,T) 'Product production' binary;

Positive Variable
    total_cost 'Total cost';

Equations
    objective 'Objective function',
    capacity_constraint 'Capacity constraint';

objective.. total_cost =e= cost_per_unit * sum((I,J,T), P(I,J,T));

capacity_constraint.. sum((I,J,T), machine_hours(I,J)*P(I,J,T) + worker_hours(I,J)*P(I,J,T)) =l= capacity;

Model production_optimization /all/;
Solve production_optimization using mip minimizing total_cost;

Display P.L, total_cost.l;

GAMS 46.4.0  2cbe6e3b Apr 2, 2024           WEX-WEI x86 64bit/MS Windows - 04/14/24 17:05:24 Page 1
G e n e r a l   A l g e b r a i c   M o d e l i n g   S y s t e m
C o m p i l a t i o n


   1  Set
   2      I 'Products' / Temse, Rye, Sandwich, Breadstick, Pepperoni /
   3      J 'Processes' / Process1, Process2 /
   4      T 'Months' / 1*12 /;
   5   
   6  Parameter
   7      capacity 'Production capacity' / 200000 /;  # Total production capacity
****                                                  $409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
   8  Scalar cost_per_unit 'Cost per unit' / 10 /;  # Cost per unit
****                                                $409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
   9   
  10  Table demand(I,T) 'Monthly demand data';
  11  demand(I,T) =
  12      140 95 400 355 210 165 80 1350 1065 500 310 120
****           $409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
  13      120 85 350 305 145 130 60 1065 915 310 285 95
  14      110 75 300 265 120 110 55 980 785 255 210 80
  15      170 115 450 395 225 180 105 1500 1180 685 335 195
  16      90 55 250 235 95 80 35 726 705 215 145 75
  17      130 85 350 345 145 130 60 1065 1035 310 285 95
  18      110 75 300 285 120 110 55 980 850 255 210 80
  19      100 70 275 255 110 85 40 820 765 240 130 65
  20      160 110 400 375 210 165 80 1350 1120 500 310 120
  21      80 50 225 215 80 75 30 670 645 195 115 50
  22      140 95 400 355 210 165 80 1350 1065 500 310 120
  23      90 55 250 235 95 80 35 726 705 215 145 75;
  24   
  25  Table machine_hours(I,J) 'Machine hours per product per process';
  26  machine_hours(I,J) =
  27      4 3
****        $409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
  28      2.15 5
  29      2.5 3.5
  30      3 2
  31      4.15 2;
  32   
  33  Table worker_hours(I,J) 'Worker hours per product per process';
  34  worker_hours(I,J) =
  35      12 8
****         $409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
  36      14 17
  37      13 9
  38      5 7
  39      11 4.5;
  40   
  41  Parameter
  42      machine_capacity(T) 'Machine capacity' /
  43          1 140,
  44          2 120,
  45          3 110,
  46          4 170,
  47          5 90,
  48          6 130,
  49          7 110,
  50          8 100,
  51          9 160,
  52          10 80,
  53          11 140,
  54          12 90 /;
  55   
  56  Parameter
  57      worker_capacity(T) 'Worker capacity' /
  58          1 95,
  59          2 85,
  60          3 75,
  61          4 115,
  62          5 55,
  63          6 85,
  64          7 75,
  65          8 70,
  66          9 110,
  67          10 50,
  68          11 95,
  69          12 55 /;
  70   
  71  Variables
  72      P(I,J,T) 'Product production' binary;
****                                          $180,2
****   2  Identifier expected
**** 180  'variable' expected
  73   
  74  Positive Variable
  75      total_cost 'Total cost';
  76   
  77  Equations
  78      objective 'Objective function',
  79      capacity_constraint 'Capacity constraint';
  80   
  81  objective.. total_cost =e= cost_per_unit * sum((I,J,T), P(I,J,T));
  82   
  83  capacity_constraint.. sum((I,J,T), machine_hours(I,J)*P(I,J,T) + worker_hours(I,J)*P(I,J,T)) =l= capacity;
  84   
  85  Model production_optimization /all/;
  86  Solve production_optimization using mip minimizing total_cost;
****                                                              $246,257
**** 246  Objective variable is not a free variable
**** 257  Solve statement not checked because of previous errors
  87   
  88  Display P.L, total_cost.l;
****            $141          $141
**** 141  Symbol declared but no values have been assigned. Check for missing
****         data definition, assignment, data loading or implicit assignment
****         via a solve statement. Suppress with $onImplicitAssign.
****         A wild shot: You may have spurious commas in the explanatory
****         text of a declaration. Check symbol reference list.

**** 11 ERROR(S)   0 WARNING(S)

`
Trying with chatgpt but didnt work

ChatGPT can be very useful in many situations, but I wonder if it is the best tool to actually learn something new. In this case, it just did not generate valid GAMS code. First and easy thing to fix is to add $eolCom # to the start of your code. Otherwise, the # is not recogniozed as end of line comment character. Next, the data definition for you "table" symbols is wrong. I'd suggest to read this to get started: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Tutorial.html (maybe it also helps to ask ChatGPT to read it and regenerate your model...)
